# UITextView UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification not being called on programmatic change of the text

Tags: ios, iphone, input, ios8, uitextview

I call this in the init of a custom UITextView:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self];
```

The method `textChanged`is not called when I programmatically set `textView.text = @""`

Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No need for observer as use [yourTextView addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

Comment: why you used notification instead of the delegate methods

Comment: i have to use this in the text view as well as its super view

Comment: @Prince I never used that before, can you please elaborate on it a little

Answer (score 5):

Your shouldn't pass `self` to the last parameter, this parameter is notificationSender, it means that you just want to observer the notifications sent by `self`.

Observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                      name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                      object:nil];
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realize this - link to docs for more color: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:

Comment: But if you don't pass self, the selector will be invoked when text is changed for any UITextView in the app which will create a lot of overhead when you multiple UITextViews in a screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class and just override text property

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {
   override var text: String! {
      didSet {
        //do your stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate pattern @Prince mentioned works as follows. Within your custom UITextView initialization:

```
[self setDelegate:self];
```

Then implement the [appropriate delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:):

```
#pragma - UITextViewDelegate

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Move the body of textChanged here
    // ...
}
```

This is a preferred way to manage responding to changes in an intimate/1:1 relationship, as outlined in [this excellent post](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/).

Comment: Nah, it just means you can't use the delegate elsewhere, as you often need to. For a "low level" change like this you just use a notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITextView {

func centerVertically() {
    let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
    let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
    let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
    contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
}
```

}

//To update the text on editing use below code.

```
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.centerVertically()
}
```