# How to invoke didChange on textView in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, ios13

I have a textView embedded in a cell in a tableView and am trying to determine whether the text has been changed when the user presses done.

When a user taps on a note, it loads the note from the database, they can make edits, and press done. When they press done I need to invoke didChange to make sure that they changed something to avoid writing the same information back to the database. I've set my cell as a UITextFieldDelegate and tried setting didChange.

```
import UIKit


class NoteEditTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var editorView: UITextView!
    var origionalContent = ""

    var didContentChange = false

    func didChange<Value>(_ changeKind: NSKeyValueChange, valuesAt indexes: IndexSet, for keyPath: __owned KeyPath<NoteEditTableViewCell, Value>) {
        debugPrint("Content Changed")
    }
}
```

I can't get didChange to invoke though. No matter what I change in that field, it never prints the debug message.

Comment: use UITextViewDelegate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631012/uitextview-uitextviewtextdidchangenotification-not-being-called-on-programmatic

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function here. You can also use callback function like this for button tap action in tableViewCell. That will respond in tableview.

1)Declare callback function in your tableViewCell file. Here this callback function pass String, you can use any type you want or you can leave it empty[()->()] if you just want to detect this function call in tableview.

```
var textViewTextChangeCallback:((String) -> Void)?
```

2) use UITextViewDelegate with textViewDidChange in your tableViewCell file. Put this extension into your tableViewCell file. call the callback function here & pass anything you want.

```
extension NoteEditTableViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewTextChangeCallback?(textView.text)
    }
 }
```

3)Define your callback closure in cellForRawAt of UITableViewDataSource in your ViewController file.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifire") as! NoteEditTableViewCell

        cell.textViewTextChangeCallback = { [unowned self] text in
            print(text)  
            // if you want to save text on buttonClick when textViewDidChange call, create callback function for buttonClick & call its's closure here. i already show you how to define callback function follow as abov for any click you want from tableViewCell ;)
        }
    }
    return cell

}
```